# Create a panorama from main camera footage of TV sports broadcasts

Tags: software, panorama, software-recommendation

I am looking for the possibility to create a panorama of a stadium/arena just by using the regular footage from the main camera of a TV sports broadcast. By that I mean I'd like to find a way to create a panorama by the main camera panning across the field/ice/court etc.
Once the whole field/ice/court has been captured, the process can stop. And as an optional last step, players should be removed to only get the actual field/ice/court.
How would I do this - preferably using existing solutions? I looked into Linux and Windows software but none I found could make this happen. Can I make this work using Hugin or OpenCV?

Comment: Are you the camera operator? Or are you giving instructions to the camera operator? Or are you just trying to achieve this by ripping images from the broadcast feed?

Answer (score 2):

Stitching images together to make a larger one is indeed the purpose of Hugin.

AFAIK it doesn't work from a video, but there are many ways to extract images from a video. On the other hand it may have expectations that aren't a given in a TV pan:

- all the images shot with the same focal length,
- pan with a rotation around a single axis

Comment: Yes, I've encountered that. Hugin doesn't like this at all. Currently on the phone with my buddy ChatGPT to figure something out :)

Comment: Hugin DOES that. You only have to separate the frames.

Comment: Expecting a truthful & accurate answer out of Chat GPT is like expecting the accused in the dock to provide an honest answer to, 'where were you on the night of the 15th?'.

Comment: @Tetsujin We worked on it together, and in the end the result wasn't bad.

Comment: @Rafael I have separated the frames, but whatever I do, Hugin will not create a panorama from them. I guessed the HFOV values, created control points manually, but all it does is stack the images, not stitching them at all. This way, I only ever see one frame...

Comment: Do not use consecutive frames. Drop a lot of them. The frames should only have, let's say. a 30% overlap. So scroll the video and decide, depending on the speed of the panning.

Comment: See if motion blur is not an issue.